# Strings with File Input without File Output

Tags: c++, string, inputstream

I'm trying to get the user to find students with a certain major with this a file that looks like this:

> Andrews,Lilian,C,X107293,Computer Science 
> Brown,Mark,J,X101276,Mechanical Engineering
> Craig,Stephen,H,X115582,Chemistry
> Davis,Deanna,M,X122755,Mathematics
> Franklin,Randall,A,X113404,Chemistry

And have to use `string::npos`, but I still have no idea what it does. From the notes and the textbook, they weren't specific with this method. Also, as you can see from the bottom, I am trying to show the user the major and the number of students with the major.
**Please tell me if I need to elaborate.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream studentInfo;
    string studentData, major;
    int studentCount = 0;
    
    studentInfo.open ("studentInfo.txt");
    if (studentInfo.fail())
    {
      cout << "Cannot open file. \n";
      exit(1);
    }
    
    cout << "Student Major Course" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter the major to search for: ";
    getline(cin, major);
    
    cout << endl;
    
    while (getline(studentInfo, studentData))
    {
        studentData += studentCount;
        major.find("Computer Science");
        major.find("Mechanical Engineering");
        major.find("Chemistry");
        major.find("History");
        major.find("English");
        major.find("Civil Engineering");
        major.find("Mathematics");
    }
    
    cout << "Total of " << major << " majors: " << studentCount << endl;

    studentInfo.close();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: The program should look like this:

> Enter the major to search for: Computer Science 
> The following are the students who match that major:
> Andrews,Lilian,C,X107293,Computer Science
> Harris,Martin,E,X104501,Computer Science
> Johnson,Anne,I,X108764,Computer Science
> Vaughn,Veronica,L,X117032,Computer Science
>  
> Total of Computer Science majors: 4

Comment: *"I still have no idea what it [`string::npos`] does."* -- I would guess rather that you have no idea what `string::npos` **is**. It is a value, and as such it does not really do anything on its own. What is the actual requirement for your assignment? (If your assignment does literally say you "have to use `string::npos`" with no further context, I'd view that as a sign that your instructor has trouble explaining assignments clearly.)

Comment: @JaMiT They told me to use `string::npos`, if the string is not found. For example, `stringexamined.find(stringfound); != string::npos`

Comment: You added a semicolon where it does not belong. Not the two statements that you wrote, but the single expression `stringexamined.find(stringfound) != string::npos`. Review what your textbook has to say about the value returned by `string::find()`.

Comment: Showing what the program should look like

Comment: Please describe in words what you expect your program to do, step-by-step.

Comment: [file:///home/chronos/u-5686407c14a9e3cfccf705575bb5a91722f02568/MyFiles/Downloads/CIS%20251%20Laboratory%20Assignment%2009.pdf]

Comment: No, not what you were assigned to do, but what you believe your program currently does. Explain why you wrote your code the way you did. Go line-by-line and explain the purpose of the line and how it relates to other lines. What are you telling the computer to do? (Remember that the computer does *only* what you tell it to do. It remembers *only* what you tell it to remember.)

Comment: Or perhaps easier: describe the steps you want your program to follow. When writing a program, one often starts with a goal (like your assignment), which is then divided into smaller steps, and each step is broken into a series of instructions (pseudocode) for the computer to follow. After that, the instructions get translated into an actual programming language (such as C++). Instead of justifying your C++ code, you could present one of the earlier phases -- preferably the pseudocode -- and focus on one detail that you cannot advance to the next phase.